# Add margins to MUI DataGrid row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I am using MUI DataGrid in React to display some data. I would like the rows to have a margin on the left and right. In other words, I don't want them to extend the full width of the table. I was able to modify some css styling to get a margin on the left, however, I can't figure out how to do this on the right side and feel like it is hacky. Example of adding margin on the left is shown below in the first row. Your help would be appreciated!

[image]